How to copy with SCP from a remote server and stop seeing "No such file or directory"?
There are a number of similar questions here.
But I spent more than four hours searching for a solution to an SCP error ("No such file or directory") that addressed my specific situation. Here's the fix:
When I try to copy a file with SSH using the SCP (Secure Copy Protocol) I receive an error

No such file or directory


This was because I was run the SCP command while logged in to the remote server. This caused the server to look for the destination folder (the one you're copying files to) on itself, which wouldn't exist.
Log out from the remote server. Repeat the command. This ensures the command runs on your local machine, allowing you to specify your local folder as the destination. And high probably you'll stop seeing the "No such file or directory"
My account reputation here doesn't allow leaving either comments or votes. That's why I'm asking and answering the question myself. Maybe this could save others hours of searching for the fix.

This answer is just basic how to not use scp properly. You can do it while logged in to the remote server you just swap local and remote around, so push this file to this dest (instead of pull from this dest this file to here)
